# How to replace the UIWebView MoviePlayer?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

The `UIWebView` use the private `UIMoviePlayerController` to play video/audio by default, but I want to replace it with `MPMoviePlayerViewController`， Can I?

I did a lot of search, but could not find a solution.

Thanks a lot.